# Error: Cannot find module '/home/admin/...'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I installed thunderhub webapp and when I initate it it appears the next:

```
Jun 10 07:22:07 minibolt systemd[1]: Started Thunderhub.
Jun 10 07:22:12 minibolt npm[645827]: (node:645827) [DEP0123] DeprecationWarning: Setting the TLS ServerName to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066. This will be ignored in a future version.
Jun 10 07:22:12 minibolt npm[645827]: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

When I type `node --trace-deprecation ...`

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/admin/...'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Can Someone help me?

Tried to `npm install ...` and `sudo npm install ...`

I get this:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/admin/.../package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/admin/.../package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-06-10T07_33_31_288Z-debug-0.log
admin@minibolt:~$ node ...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^
```

If you coud help me...